# Magento: Setting products to be active in all my frontends

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, e-commerce

Current Config: (Magento version 1.4.0.1)

- 3 frontends (websites)
- 1 backend
- 3 different url's (one for each frontend)
- 3 separate theme packs.

After setting this up I found that I must manually edit each product to set each storeview active.

How can I set all my products to be active on all 3 frontends ?
(I had looked a bit into Magento API but couldn't find a way.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Nasaralla's comments I found out the right calls in Magento api.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
$proxy = new SoapClient('https://website.com/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('user', 'password');
$filters = array();

$products = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product.list', array($filters));
$i = 0;
foreach($products as $product){
        $sku = $product["sku"];
        if($i>365 and !empty($sku)){
                $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product.update', array($sku, array('websites'=> array('1','2','3'))));
                print $sku. "\n";
        }
        $i++;
}
print "done";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you backend when you are in manage catalog products, on the left you have your website ('Choose Store View:') and if you make that default store ('Default Values'), you should get the same settings in all stores.

Comment: I want to automatically (not manually) enable my products on all my front ends, thanks.

Comment: You can import products from System > import /export and selecting import all products. If you simply want to activate all the products you already have then you can do it using a simple mysql script on catalog_product_entity_int table... setting attribute_id to 80 (you can check that in eav_attributes table), and set all values to '1'... '1' is enabled and '2' is disabled.